# slack api for huddle

Tags: slack, slack-api

I did some research and I can see there is almost nothing for developers to use regarding Huddles in slack api.
But... I have found next two links so I see possibilities and questions are raising:

- [LINK1](https://jasonaa.notion.site/Join-Huddle-2e150d931336454397cb632d62d27715)
- [LINK2](https://jasonaa.notion.site/figuring-out-the-slack-huddles-api-1220507c034046669887287112f54049)
- Question1 - Is it possible to get huddle link through python script over API or some hacky way? (for each new slack channel created)
- Question2 - Would it be possible to raise a call over huddle with python script using slack API because links i provided are pointing to a possibility, but due to my limitation in understanding i would require any form of help/explanation/assistance.
  (Altho is first question is solved then raising a call is easy over a script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stepping back and allowing myself to see the forest for the trees, I found that I don't need a python script to catch network traffic when simulating a website request...

SOLUTION:
`https://app.slack.com/huddle/{team_id}/{channel_id}`

Comment: How can you retrieve such values? team_id, channel_id?